# How do I click on one of the values in a list and put the text into a text box?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, autosuggest

I'm trying to do an autosuggest search box and I have everything working but I can't find a way so that when I click on one of the items in the list to have that text go into the textbox. I also need the list to disappear once once this happens. Does anybody have an idea how to do this? Please find my code attached:

Index.php

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function findmatch() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }

    }

xmlhttp.open('GET', 'search.inc.php?search_text='+document.search.search_text.value,         true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}



</script>
</head>
<body>




<form id="search" name="search">

Type a name:<br />
<input type="text"  id = "search_text" name="search_text"  onkeyup="findmatch();">
</form>
<ul>
<div id="results"></div>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Search.inc.php

```
<?php


if (isset($_GET['search_text'])) {
$search_text = $_GET['search_text'];
}

if (!empty($search_text)){

if (@mysql_connect('localhost','username','password')) {
if (@mysql_select_db('Database')){

                $query = "SELECT name FROM Customers WHERE name LIKE     '$search_text%'";
                $query_run = mysql_query($query);


                while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){

                    $id = "id".$i;
                    echo "<li>".$name = $query_row['name']."    </li>";

                }

        }
}

}


?>
```

Comment: The code you posted has nothing to do with clicking elements, and it doesn't even include a textbox, all it does is load list items.  What have you tried to achieve your desired behavior?

Comment: Yeah, that's my bad, I noticed that after I saw the answer.  Regardless, most of your posted code is not directly relevant to the question you asked.  Just a friendly suggestion to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't calling your Clicked() function from anywhere. Try adding an event to the list items you are outputting:

```
echo "<li onclick='Clicked(this)'>".$name = $query_row['name']."    </li>";
```

And you will also want to know what was clicked in your Clicked function"

```
function Clicked(li)
{
    document.getElementById("aaa").value = li.innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = '';
    return false; // so no postback
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much for your help